Is Genetic Diversity Or Genetic Homogeny More Likely Over Long Periods Of Time?
I have two separate species. One species has multiple subspecies within it that are all roughly similar in appearance and body structure. The other species, although all subspecies are capable of crossbreeding with one another, are diverse enough in appearance and body structure that hybridization between the subspecies is null. My question is, which species is more likely to be the older?
TLDR: Over an extended period of time, is it more likely that a number of species will become more genetically similar or more genetically diverse?
Edit: Thanks to those who have answered or commented. I realize now that the question was too broad, and if anyone feels the need to edit in order to make it clearer, please feel free to do so. I apologize for any frustration or confusion I caused. Have a great rest of your day/week/year!

This might be Too Story-Based. Without details, my knee-jerk reaction is that your subspecies can't be too dissimilar or they can't interbreed. Given that, the failure to interbreed is cultural, not hereditary. Add to this that what dissimilarities are found are almost always a function of geography/isolation and not purely genetics. I guess the long-and-short of my comment is, given that how evolution works is a lot less scientifically-predictable (as we understand it today) than you might think, what is it about the genetic and cultural history of humanity that fails to answer your question?

It Depends ## There are two factors here: 1. What is causing the diversity?

What is eliminating the diversity? If one lives in a setting where there are more mutagenic substances, and more population isolation allowing for genetic drift, and the other lives in a setting with more epidemic diseases, thus increasing the benefit of genetic diversity within in a population and so that of outbreeding, making subspecies interbreeding a survival trait -- it would be anyone's guess which is older. Especially since the factors could have been more or less severe in periods in history.


If the several populations of the "other species" are reproductively isolated, why do you call them subspecies? It doesn't matter that if they wanted to they could; what matters is that they don't. If they don't actually interbreed, for whatever reason, they are reproductively isolated and they are evolving independently. They are full separate species. And, quite obviously, separate species can only diverge genetically, as there is nothing which would tend to reduce the genetic distance between them.

Creatures mutate at their own rate, dogs much faster than cats for example with the majority of breeds of dogs coming about through selective breeding over the last 180 years - whereas cat-breeds are still remarkably similar after thousands of years. There's no information in the question that could provoke other than an opinion-based answer. Do you really mean genetic diversity as opposed to phenotypic diversity? Please clarify.

What is the Geographic conditions - as this has a great deal of impact on the issue

This is likely to depend strongly on size. Larger populations will take more time for mutations to spread and have more individuals to actually mutate. Similarly it makes a difference whether a population has increased in size recently or had that size for a while. So, what sizes are you thinking of?

I accidentally voted to close as opinion-based, what I should have done is ask for more details and clarity. Can you tell us about their breeding strategy and the time between generations?

If members of a species all live in the same environment, they’re likely to become more similar as natural selection does its thing. Random mutations are going to occur and will either be spread to a large portion of the population or phased out.
If members of a species live very spread out from each other and in different environments, the way they adapt and evolve will be different. The only way you get subspecies is by a genetic mutation occurring and only spreading to PART of the population but not to the rest. The most likely reason for this is they simply live somewhere else.
It’s not really about how old either species is, it’s about their environment.

Again, thanks to everyone for trying and I am really sorry for the confusion. However, I have figured it out! The age of mixed society
Species A, the genetically diverse, have only had mixed society for a short period of time, think a few hundred years/several generations. Assuming each "subspecies", which I will now refer to as "races", developed in isolation from the other races in a very specific environment, only certain genes would (A) present themselves and (B) survive the culling process of natural selection. Because Genetically Diverse Species's (GDS) has only recently been interacting with other races, there has been no time for crossbreeding to become commonplace enough that any visible effects have occured.
This is the opposite with Genetically Homogeneous Species (GHS). The GHS have had mixed society for a very long time. In fact, part of their mythology states that all races were once one and were forced to travel to other environments in order to survive. After this, the various races were allowed to slowly change in appearance and abilities based on their environment. However, the various races of GHS founded mixed societies hundreds of thousands of years ago, and have regained their original, more homogeneous state by the time the story begins. Many apologies if this doesn't help anyone who has a similar question to mine; this works for me, but feel free to continue adding answers and editing my question if that helps anyone. :D
